# How are airspace violations detected?

Tags: airspace, transponder, altimeter

Are airspace violations (e.g. entry to class B without clearance) based on primary radar and/or Mode C transponder, or something else?

I read that Mode C altitude is [based on pressure altitude](http://www.airsport-corp.com/modec.htm), i.e., set to 29.92" ... but presumably that's adjusted at the ATC facility based on the current pressure before being used for altitude enforcement.

This begs the question, what would stop one (hypothetically), just winding back the altimeter pressure reading to appear to be at a lower altitude?

So to summarize: How are airspace violations detected:

1. What data input is used?
2. If Mode C reading is used, is it based
   on pilot's altimeter?
3. Would winding back the altimeter make a
   plane report a lower altitude?

Comment: I busted class D one time by about 0.3 to 0.5 miles and they did not really care.

Comment: @SpongeBob I probably have too... I'm more concerned with busting class B without a clearance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The transponder usually uses its own pressure reading, not what is set in the pilot's altimeter. So to prevent cheating as you describe, it is inspected and calibrated every 24 months. Tampering with it would be difficult to do on the fly because you'd have to adjust it based on the current atmospheric conditions and what altitude you want to seem to fly at. But yes, you could, in theory, adjust its readings to broadcast something different.

As far as I'm aware, only major violations are really pursued, or if ATC knows who you are when you commit the violation.

Comment: Yes, I saw this about the aftermath: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9/i-just-flew-into-class-b-airspace-without-a-clearance-now-what

Comment: Does this mean that primary radar is used for, say Class D (and perhaps C) airspace, which, in the U.S., a Mode C transponder isn't required for?

Comment: @CJBS I'm not sure what you mean, related to the topic. A lot of Class D's don't even have radar, or they might only be tied in to the radar of a nearby class C.

Comment: If you *really screwed up* (like "cut through the heart of the New York Class B airspace squawking VFR and not talking to anybody") ATC will probably follow you on their scope, determine where you're landing, and you'll receive "the dreaded phone number" to call when you land (either from local ATC, or they'll call the uncontrolled field you landed and ask "Who was that plane that landed at your field at 1320 Zulu?")

Comment: @StallSpin - I was implying that, for such fields (Class D or C airspace), if there's no primary radar, and/or an aircraft doesn't have altimeter reporting equipment, then it's not possible to track violations of such airspace.

Comment: @CJBS That's correct, as far as I am aware.

Comment: @CJBS An eagle-eyed tower controller who knows their airspace and local landmarks could probably issue violations visually, but I doubt that's common practice (again, unless the pilot *really screws up* and is doing something like overflying a class D airport at 1500 feet directly over the field not talking to anyone) If you're close enough that they can read your N number without binoculars and you're not talking to them there might be something said :)

Comment: @voretaq7 - Laterally, this is probably true, but vertically (unless a gross violation, like you mention), this would be difficult. Vertical boundaries change as the pressure changes, and there are few reference points in the air.

Comment: @CJBS Airspace doesn't change with air pressure... You adjust the altimeter for pressure variations so that it reads the correct altitude. The only airspace that can change with pressure is Class A, but they don't assign aircraft to the couple-thousand feet in conflict.

Comment: @StallSpin - You're absolutely right. I'm mistaken - thanks for the correction. I suppose it comes down to how often altimeter variations are updated (e.g. METAR) by the tower, but even then, it's probably not significant. Still difficult to judge how high something is accurately though.

Comment: @StallSpin they won't assign  FL180 when the altimeter is below 29.92, but they can when its above

Answer (score 3):

In the event of a disagreement between the transponder altitude and the pilot's stated altitude ATC is required to go with what you tell them on the radio. So if their screen says you are at 18,000 but you say "no, I'm at 15,000" they go with that number. Therefore, if you do fudge your numbers a bit for whatever reason, ATC will be unable to do anything about it. They will also not issue avoidance vectors to the A340 approaching head-on at 0.8mach - you are, after all, 3000 feet lower than the Airbus.

Regarding the "dreaded phone number to call" - once you have landed and parked you are no longer air traffic and no longer required to follow their instructions. In many cases the FAA cannot issue you a violation without your co-operation, so don't give them any.

Comment: FAR 91.217 deals with discrepancies http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?node=14:2.0.1.3.10#se14.2.91_1217